# unordered_multimap element insert

Tags: c++, boost, dictionary

I tried to insert a value into a boost unordered_multimap using the following code but that didn't work since it doesnt compile. Why is there no access [] operator?

The insert() method doesn't work either?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   typedef boost::unordered_multimap<
      int,
      boost::unordered_multimap<
         int,
         boost::unordered_multimap<int, int>
      >
   > unordered_map;

   unordered_map _3d;

   _3d[0][0][0] = 10;
   _3d[0][0][0].insert(10);

   cout << _3d[0][0][0] << endl;
}
```

Errors:

> multimap.cpp||In function `'int main()'`:
>   multimap.cpp|19|error: no match for `'operator[]'` in `'_3d[0]'`
>   multimap.cpp|21|error: no match for `'operator[]'` in `'_3d[0]'`
>   ||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings ===

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What error did you get? My ESP is on the fritz today, so you're gonna have to help me to help you.

Comment: I edited the above with the error.

Comment: `std::multimap` doesn't have `operator[]` either -- why would you expect `unordered_multimap` to?

Comment: @ildjarn I've never tried using std::multimap. Isn't unordered_multimap boost only?

Comment: @lost_with_coding : `unordered_multimap` is also in TR1 in the `std::tr1` namespace, and in C++0x in the `std` namespace. In all cases, it is modeled after `std::multimap`, which again does not have an `operator[]` -- how could it? What type would it return?

Comment: @ildjarn: Its type is well-defined. Its value is a little more complicated.

Comment: @Tomalak : Okay, I'll bite -- what is the result type of `std::multimap::operator[]`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neither `unordered_multimap` nor `multimap` supports `operator[]` because it's not well-defined what it would mean.  The idea behind `operator[]` is that you could write `myMap[key]` to mean "the **unique** value associated with `key` in `myMap`."  When dealing with a `unordered_multimap`, this isn't mathematically well-defined; there can be many key-value pairs with the same key in the multimap, and it's unclear which particular value you'd like to have.

From the example you gave, it seems like you really want to have a standard `unordered_map` rather than an `unordered_multimap`.  If you're trying to use a map of map of maps to represent some higher-dimensional array, then you probably only want to have each coordinate map to one particular subspace.  Replacing `unordered_multimap` with `unordered_map` should fix this.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

[`boost::unordered_map` doesn't appear to have `operator[]`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_multimap.html). Use the lookup functions instead.

What reference are you using?

Comment: Whatever I can find on google which isn't much. I usually try to find examples but it seems no one uses this stuff or theres a secret society on the internets that does and isn't transparent in the "offerings" of examples.

Comment: @lost_with_coding: Use the documentation.